# Dependent mapped types appear as 'any' when accessing index in nested object

Tags: typescript

I am trying to set up a nested object structure where the keys of the two layers are enum values, but the enum used for the second level depends on the value of the first level. I have types working that do this, but when I try accessing an index I get 'any' as the type of the child.

Here is an example.

```
enum BaseKey {
  FIRST = 'first',
  SECOND = 'second',
}

enum FirstChildren {
  FIRST_1 = 'first1',
  FIRST_2 = 'first2',
}

enum SecondChildren {
  SECOND_1 = 'second1',
  SECOND_2 = 'second2',
}

// This map identifies which child enum is associated with each BaseKey
const KeyMap = {
  [BaseKey.FIRST]: Object.values(FirstChildren),
  [BaseKey.SECOND]: Object.values(SecondChildren),
} as const;

// The type here enforces that each BaseKey must be defined on 'example'
// and that the nested object must have all mapped child enum values as keys
export const example: {
  [baseKey in BaseKey]: {
    [childKey in typeof KeyMap[baseKey][number]]: number;
  };
} = {
  [BaseKey.FIRST]: {
    [FirstChildren.FIRST_1]: 5,
    [FirstChildren.FIRST_2]: 6,
  },
  [BaseKey.SECOND]: {
    [SecondChildren.SECOND_1]: 1,
    [SecondChildren.SECOND_2]: 2,
  },
};

export function processKeys(baseKey: BaseKey, childKey: FirstChildren | SecondChildren) {
  // example[baseKey] returns a union of the childKey object types
  // so accessing like this means value becomes 'any'
  const value = example[baseKey][childKey];
  console.log(value);
}
```

Ideally 'value' would have type 'number', since the childKey is a union of enums where all options are properties on the nested object in 'example'. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish something like this using generics. Although it doesn't quite resolve `value` to be `number`, it allows you to manually annotate `value` as a `number` without any issues.

But before diving into that, you should first consider if it's worth the trouble to massage the types just for this one index access, or if a simple `@ts-ignore` comment would be more manageable:

```
export function processKeys(baseKey: BaseKey, childKey: FirstChildren | SecondChildren) {
  // @ts-ignore: I know it's a number, and this is easier than generics!
  const value = example[baseKey][childKey];
  console.log(value);

  return value;
}
```

---

But if you really want to avoid the comment, here is one approach.

First, I would set up the `processKeys` function so that it will only accept valid pairs of `baseKey` and `childKey`. Eg., disallow using `BaseKey.First` along with `SecondChildren.SECOND_1`. You might accomplish that like so:

```
export function processKeys<K extends BaseKey, CK extends typeof KeyMap[K][number]>(baseKey: K, childKey: CK) {
  const value = example[baseKey][childKey];
  console.log(value);
}
```

Now, if you inspect the type of `value`, we get the unhelpful looking type:

```
{
    first: {
        first1: number;
        first2: number;
    };
    second: {
        second1: number;
        second2: number;
    };
}[K][CK]
```

However, all this means is that the type of `value` is based on the particular choices of `K` and `CK`, which aren't known until the function is executed.

Now, it would be ideal if TS would collapse this type to just `number`, as it's clear that no matter which combination of `K` and `CK` are chosen, the result is always a `number`.

Despite that shortcoming, TS is still able to determine two things: that `example[baseKey][childKey]` is a valid access *and* that the resulting value is assignable to `number`.

Given that the value can be assigned to `number`, you can now use a manual annotation to narrow it, without any TS errors:

```
const value: number = example[baseKey][childKey]; // Note the number type annotation. No errors here!
```

---

Comment: For the generics approach, is there a way to enforce that type if the arguments are actually properties on an object? E.g.  
  
```type TExample = { baseKey: BaseKey; childKey: FirstChildren | SecondChildren; }```  
```export function processKeys(obj: TExample)...```